# If a relation $R$ on $A$ is not reflexive, $R^2$ on $A$ is also not reflexive

Tags: proof-verification, relations

A relation $\rho$ is not reflexive if there exists some $a\in A$ which is not related to itself, i.e. $\exists a:a\not\rho a$.
$\rho^2$ means the relation applied twice.

Is there a direct proof of this claim?

> If a relation $R$ on $A$ is not reflexive, $R^2$ on $A$ is also not reflexive.

I can think of some counterexamples. Assume there is one such and let this be $a_1$.

Then $a_1\rho a_1 = a_2$. Since $a_2\ne a_1$, $a_2$ must be reflexive.
$\implies a_2 \rho a_2$ is reflexive.
$\implies a_1 \rho^2a_1$ is reflexive.

Hence we have found a case where a relation $R$ where the relation is not reflexive is true but "$R^2$ is also not reflexive" is false.

Hence the claim is false.

Comment: Most of what you have written does not make sense.  For instance, what does "a$_1$ R a$_1$ = a$_2$" mean?  What does "a$_2$ R^2 is also reflexive"  mean?

Comment: What do you mean by $a_1 Ra_1=a_2$? This notation is vague.

Comment: The relation $R=\{(a_1,a_2), (a_2,a_1)\}$ on $\{a_1,a_2\}$ is non-reflexive. Its square is $R^2=\{(a_1,a_1), (a_2,a_2)\}$ is reflexive.

Comment: $a\ \rho\  b$ can be only true or false it is equivalent with $(a, b) \in \rho$ or $(a, b) \not\in \rho$.

Comment: How can you simultaneously “think of some counter examples” and ask for a proof?

Comment: I asked is there a direct proof though I could also construct a counter example.  Any counterexample would do since the claim is for any set A.